# document.querySelector based on data-bind name

Tags: javascript

```
<span data-automation="name" data-bind="text: ContactInformation.PersonName.fullName">John Smith</span>
```

I have a Chrome Extension which scrapes certain element values from the page. Traditionally these have an ID or class name that I can use, but here I only have a data-bind or data-automation property.

Is there any way to use document.querySelector here to return the innerText of this span?

Comment: There are plenty of ways. You can select by `<span>`, select by attribute `data-automation="name"`, etc. You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: This is all the information I've been given from the client. I'm wondering if I can do something like `document.querySelector("[data-bind]=text: ContactInformation.PersonName.fullName").innerText`

Comment: In other words, per your comment, I'd like to select by the attribute data-bind.

Comment: Something like `document.querySelector("[data-bind*=fullName]");` might work, but I'm not sure how reliable that is in regards to only grabbing *this* element without seeing the context of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you may use [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```js
 var x = document.querySelector("[data-bind='text: ContactInformation.PersonName.fullName']").textContent;
 
 console.log(x);
```

```html
<span data-automation="name" data-bind="text: ContactInformation.PersonName.fullName">John Smith</span>
```